# Android Studio change color scheme of constant and static fields in Kotlin code

Tags: android-studio, color-scheme

I'm looking for a way to change constant value color scheme in Kotlin code.

Here is an example image from my IDE; here, I want to change `TAG` and `BASE_URL` field colors to something else like Java static finals, `but not for all fields`:

[image: ide color scheme]

I tried to find a key in color scheme settings, but I couldn't find any special element there to change it.

Is there any solution for this right now?